# VNC Setting to Connect to Ubuntu Server with LXQt Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, lxqt

I have installed LXQt on Ubuntu Server. I can connect to it with XRDP just fine.

Then I tried to setup TigerVNC. This fails and results in a desktop that does not respond properly. For example, I cannot open the file manager but terminal opens fine.

This is the `xstartup` file content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startlxqt &
```

Am I missing something in the `xstartup` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This solution](https://www.gaggl.com/2014/06/ubuntu-14-04-amazon-ec2-cloud-desktop-using-lxqt/) seems to work and provide similar desktop as xrdp.

Create `~/.vnc/xstartup` file and paste the following content.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
exec openbox-session &
startlxqt &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```